# How to inject validator in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

Can somebody show me how I would inject validator into a regular class using dependency injection.

In my controller I have :

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Form;

class FormController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = new Form();
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $valid = $form->isValid($email);
    }
}
```

and I want to use this custom class - but I need it got have access to validator.

```
class Form {
    public function isValid($value)
    {
        // This is where I fail
        $validator = $this->get('validator'); 
        ... etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this, your custom class will need to be defined as a service, and you'll access it from the controller using `$form = $this->get('your.form.service');` instead of instantiating it directly.

When defining your service, make sure to inject the validator service:

```
your.form.service:
    class: Path\To\Your\Form
    arguments: [@validator]
```

Then you'll need to handle this in the construct method of your Form service:

```
/**
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator
 */
protected $validator;

function __construct(\Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, totally get it now!

Answer (score 4):

In Symfony 4+, if you use the default configuration (with auto wiring enabled), the easiest way is to inject a `ValidatorInterface`.

For instance:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class MySuperClass
{
    private $validator;

    public function __construct(
        ValidatorInterface $validator
    ) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

From Symfony2.5 on

`Validator` is called `RecursiveValidator` so, for injection

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator;
function __construct(RecursiveValidator $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Form class can inherit from ContainerAware (Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware). Then you will have access to the container and you will be able to get the validator service like this:

```
$validator = $this->container->get('validator');
```